# pygame screen failing to display

Tags: python, pygame, surface

I have the following code in Python 3 (and pygame), but the white surface fails to display and I don't understand why. Has it got something to do with where it has been placed? I tried de-indenting, but that didn't work either? The code is as below:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


# Variable to keep our main loop running
running = True

# Our main loop!
while running:
    # for loop through the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for KEYDOWN event; KEYDOWN is a constant defined in pygame.locals, which we imported earlier
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # If the Esc key has been pressed set running to false to exit the main loop
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            # Check for QUIT event; if QUIT, set running to false
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                running = False

            # Create the surface and pass in a tuple with its length and width
            surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
            # Give the surface a color to differentiate it from the background
            surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
            rect = surf.get_rect()

            screen.blit(surf, (400, 300))
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: _"I tried de-indenting, but that didn't work either?"_ - Yeah, don't do that. Randomly indenting and de-denting your code, will not help you.

Comment: leaf - your comment is not terribly helpful either. I meant de-indenting the code that pertains to the surface drawing. Tristan - no, no error. Just a blank black screen

Comment: @pythoncarrot But the whole reason that your window is not displaying, is because of your indention.

Comment: incorrect. The program works perfectly. (I may have pasted it in wrong to stackoverflow as it messed up my indentation). It's just when I add the surface bit, that it doesn't draw.Note the edit above - when used like that - a black screen is displayed, but not the desired surface.

Comment: @pythoncarrot so your indentation is a result of you posting this on Stack?

Comment: I need some suggestions on how to get the surface bit to work. If you have any, as opposed to sarcasm, then that'd be great!

Comment: @pythoncarrot Please don't be that way. I'm not being sarcastic. I'm honestly asking you if this was the your code was indented before, or after you posted your code. Me being able to help depends on that question. And can we please keep this conversation friendly :)?

Answer (score 0):

So it does appear that your indentation is wrong.

You need to define the surface and update the screen etc. outside of the event loop.

At the very least you must move the `screen.blit(surf, (400, 300))` and `pygame.display.flip()` outside of the event loop.

This is it fixed:

```
# Our main loop!
while running:
    # for loop through the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for KEYDOWN event; KEYDOWN is a constant defined in pygame.locals, which we imported earlier
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # If the Esc key has been pressed set running to false to exit the main loop
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            # Check for QUIT event; if QUIT, set running to false
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                running = False

    # Create the surface and pass in a tuple with its length and width
    surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
    # Give the surface a color to differentiate it from the background
    surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
    rect = surf.get_rect()

    screen.blit(surf, (400, 300))
    pygame.display.flip()
```